# Not able to show Image in Grid View using iCloud storage?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, icloud

i am working with images to  iCloud storage. using [this link](https://github.com/rwenderlich/PhotoKeeper)  sample code i am implementing. but here i am using grid view to show the images. for Grid View i am using `AQGridView` Sample. now i got some problem while implementing  this.

my project working fine in local storage but its not working in `iCloud` storage.  while add image to grid view only one view added but completion of process it removed from view  and also i didn't get `CloudURL`.

here some main  code

```
    - (void)processiCloudFiles:(NSNotification *)notification {

// Always disable updates while processing results
[_query disableUpdates];

[_iCloudURLs removeAllObjects];

// The query reports all files found, every time.

NSArray * queryResults = [_query results];

for (NSMetadataItem * result in queryResults) {

    NSURL * fileURL = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];

    NSNumber * aBool = nil;

    // Don't include hidden files
    [fileURL getResourceValue:&aBool forKey:NSURLIsHiddenKey error:nil];

    if (aBool && ![aBool boolValue]) {

        [_iCloudURLs addObject:fileURL];

        NSLog(@"%@",_iCloudURLs);



    }

}

NSLog(@"Found %d iCloud files.", _iCloudURLs.count);

_iCloudURLsReady = YES;

if ([self iCloudOn]) {

    NSLog(@"%d",_objects.count);

    // Remove deleted files
    // Iterate backwards because we need to remove items form the array

    for (int i = _objects.count -1; i >= 0; --i) {

        PTKEntry * entry = [_objects objectAtIndex:i];

        if (![_iCloudURLs containsObject:entry.fileURL]) {

            [self removeEntryWithURL:entry.fileURL];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",_iCloudURLs);

    // Add new files
    for (NSURL * fileURL in _iCloudURLs) {

        [self loadDocAtURL:fileURL];
    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;

}

if (_moveLocalToiCloud) {

    _moveLocalToiCloud = NO;
    [self localToiCloudImpl];

}
else if (_copyiCloudToLocal) {

    _copyiCloudToLocal = NO;
    [self iCloudToLocalImpl];

}

[_query enableUpdates];

 }
```

and also i show my console Flow of my Application please help me

```
 2013-02-19 13:29:26.159 XXXX[337:907] iCloud available at: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXXX~com~XXXX~XXXX/
 2013-02-19 13:29:32.847 XXXX[337:907] No longer watching iCloud dir...
 2013-02-19 13:29:32.849 XXXX[337:907] Starting to watch iCloud dir...
 2013-02-19 13:29:33.002 XXXX[337:907] Found 0 iCloud files.
 2013-02-19 13:29:33.004 XXXX[337:907] local => iCloud impl
 2013-02-19 13:29:38.697 XXXX[337:907] Want to create file at file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXX~com~XXXX~XXXX/Documents/iBoast_Art_Soodu.ibt
 2013-02-19 13:29:38.781 XXXX[337:907] File created at file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXX~com~XXXX~XXXX/Documents/iBoast_Art_Soodu.ibt
 2013-02-19 13:29:38.790 XXXX[337:907] load table
 2013-02-19 13:30:38.563 XXXX[337:907] button index: 1
 2013-02-19 13:30:41.595 XXXX[337:907] iCloud available at: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXX~com~XXXX~XXXX/
 2013-02-19 13:30:41.607 XXXX[337:907] No longer watching iCloud dir...
 2013-02-19 13:30:41.612 XXXX[337:907] Starting to watch iCloud dir...
 2013-02-19 13:30:41.780 XXXX[337:907] Success to close file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/XXXX~com~XXXX~XXXX/Documents/iBoast_Art_Soodu.ibt
 2013-02-19 13:30:41.790 XXXX[337:907] load table
 2013-02-19 13:30:42.011 XXXX[337:907] Found 0 iCloud files.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an authoritative answer for this, but I would definitely suspect that this is a timing issue.  I'd expect to see some delegate action going on to know when an iCloud item is uploaded.

I'd also improve your logging a bit.  The line

```
NSLog(@"%@",_iCloudURLs);
```

Should have a better format.  Without this, I can't be sure, but it looks like this line is never reached.